# Adding number of lines of files in different directories using Bash

Tags: bash

I would like to count the total number of lines of files in different directory. My directory are named by year, e.g. 2000. My code are as follows

```
OLDIFS="$IFS"
IFS=""
sum=0
for year in $(seq 2014 2015)
do
    for filename in "/media/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/uncompressed/$year/*.txt"
    do
        echo $year;
        a=($(wc -l  $filename));
        sum=$(($sum + $a));
    done
done
echo $sum
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

I encountered two errors. The first one is regarding $year in the filename search. The error messages is

```
2014
2015
wc: '/media/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/uncompressed/2014'$'\n''2015/*.txt': No such file or directory
```

The second error is regarding to line count.

```
a=($(wc -l  $filename))
```

If I run this line in my Ubuntu terminal, it assigns the line number to a. Once I put it into a script, and run it using sh myscript.sh, I got following error

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done")
```

If I remove the outer parenthesis, it assigns the string '1234 finename' to a.

Comment: `for filename in "/media/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/uncompressed/$year/"*.txt`  (notice where the double-quote ends...) If the `'*'` is within the quotes, expansion does not occur. `a=($(wc -l  "$filename"));` *always* quote your variables (even in `$(...)`) Always paste your code in [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check. You will want `a=($(wc -l  < "$filename"));` to prevent the filename from following the line count.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for comment.  I still got similar error:   can't open .../uncompressed/2014
2015/*.txt: No such file

Comment: `.../uncompressed/2014 2015/*.txt:` -- that looks like a problem with your `$(seq 2014 2015)` *command substitution*. That's the only way you get `"2014 2015"` for your `year` variable. Run `seq 2014 2015` on the command line and ensure it does what it is supposed to. Get rid of the command substitution altogether since it is just 2-years and do `for year in 2014 2015; do ...` Run your script with `bash -x scriptname` to debug and find where the problem starts.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for pointing out the error. It turns out the error was caused by change IFS. I moved the IFS changing part to be inside the year loop. Now it works OK. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: That will do it. Glad you got it working. Good luck with your scripting!